# Pushdown filter in case of spark structured Delta streaming

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I have a use case where we need to stream Open Source Delta table into multiple queries, filtered on one of the partitioned column.
Eg,.
Given Delta-table partitioned on year column.

```
Streaming query 1
spark.readStream.format("delta").load("/tmp/delta-table/").
where("year= 2013")

Streaming query 2
spark.readStream.format("delta").load("/tmp/delta-table/").
where("year= 2014")
```

The physical plan shows filter after the streaming.

```
> == Physical Plan == Filter (isnotnull(year#431) AND (year#431 = 2013))
> +- StreamingRelation delta, []
```

My question is does pushdown predicate works with Streaming queries in Delta?
Can we stream only specific partition from the Delta?

Answer (score 1):

If the column is already partitioned, only the required partition will be scanned.

Let's create both partitioned and non-partitioned delta table and perform structured streaming.

Partitioned delta table streaming:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
import spark.implicits._
    
//sample dataframe
val df = Seq((1,2020),(2,2021),(3,2020),(4,2020),
(5,2020),(6,2020),(7,2019),(8,2019),(9,2018),(10,2020)).toDF("id","year")
    
//partionBy year column and save as delta table
df.write.format("delta").partitionBy("year").save("delta-stream")
    
//streaming delta table
spark.readStream.format("delta").load("delta-stream")
.where('year===2020)
.writeStream.format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

physical plan of above streaming query: Notice the partitionFilters

[image]

Non-partitioned delta table streaming:

```
df.write.format("delta").save("delta-stream")

spark.readStream.format("delta").load("delta-stream")
    .where('year===2020)
    .writeStream.format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

physical plan of above streaming query: Notice the pushedFilters

[image]

Comment: Are you using Open source or Databricks version?
In OSS push down filter is not present.
Updating the question to mention the Open source version.

Comment: @AmitJoshi- Open source

Comment: Can you pls let me now the version of Delta core used?

Comment: spark 3.0.1 and delta-core 0.7.0

Comment: I am not sure, but I cannot see the pushed filter. Can you please paste the code where to print the execution plan. May be it is getting truncated for me.

Comment: You can easily check that on spark UI - <hostname>:4040 or using df.explain(true)

Comment: I am not sure how did you get the pushdown, I executed your code and this is what I got:
  spark.readStream.format("delta").load("/tmp/delta-test")
    .where('year===2020)
    .explain(true)

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(year#409) AND (year#409 = 2020))
+- StreamingRelation delta, [id#408, year#409]

Comment: Could you please check the spark UI once, there you get complete job information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229158/discussion-between-amit-joshi-and-mohana-b-c).